# Best Practice Springs Kafka Consumer: What kind of message should the consumer receive

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I need to start working with kafka. I have a hard time getting my head around on what should the Consumer receive:
From what I understand we can configure the consumer in multiple ways:

example 1:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic_name)
public void receiveSimpleString(@Payload String message) {
}
```

example 2:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic_name)
public void receiveConsumerRecord(@Payload ConsumerRecord<String, String> message) {
}
```

example 3:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic_name)
public void receiveObject(@Payload SomeCustomClass message) {
}
```

example 4:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic_name)
public void receiveSpringMessage(@Payload org.springframework.messaging.Message<T> message) {
}
```

Maybe there are even more ways, but those once are what i mostly saw while researching for kafka+spring.

The question now is:

**Is there a best practice on what the consumer should receive?
Are there pros/cons of the different examples?**

Answer (score 6):

There is no golden rule for this and it all depends on your specific use case. Some, including myself, would prefer receiving data via a `ConsumerRecord` instance. This way you not only have access to the actual payload but also to the whole meta data coming with it.

It might be worth for you to look into [Kafka Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/). This is usually the pattern used when consuming from Kafka and producing to Kafka because of the `exactly once delivery`.